# Populate MySQL DB from $xml

Tags: php, mysql, xml, populate

How to populate MySQL DB from $xml defined as follows?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($line);
```

Is there any predefine function that automates some parts of this job? Or do I need to use DOM?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239283/efficient-way-to-update-populate-a-mysql-database-with-external-xml

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work. I have used the following code, and worked well for me.
This code not only adds data for one xml file but can be used for multiple xml files.

```
    <?php

        // table headers --> SNo  Field  Value 

        $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password"); 
        if (!$connection) {
            die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
        }

        $db_select = mysql_select_db("forms_data",$connection);
        if (!$db_select) {
            die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
        }

        mysql_query("CREATE table form_try11(id int(11) not null auto_increment,
                     Field varchar(100), 
                     Value varchar(100),
                     primary key(id)
                    )");


       $file1="C:\webserver\Apache\htdocs\php_json\file1.xml";
       $file2="C:\webserver\Apache\htdocs\php_json\file2.xml";
       $file3="C:\webserver\Apache\htdocs\php_json\file3.xml";

      $path_arr = Array($file1,$file2,$file3);

      for($count1=0; $count1<count($path_arr); $count1++){
      $xml = simplexml_load_file($path_arr[$count1]);
      $string= json_encode($xml);     

      $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($string, TRUE)),
            RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

          foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
                if(is_array($val) || $key=="xmlns:xfa" || $key=="xfa:dataNode") {

                    continue;
                } 
                else {

                        $db_insert= mysql_query("INSERT INTO form_try11(Field,Value) VALUES('$key','$val') ");

                        if (!$db_insert) {
                            die("Database insert failed: " . mysql_error());
                        } 
                   }  
            }  



    }


    mysql_close($connection);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

No predefined functions that I know of, but you can do the following:

See all the variables using

```
var_dump($xml);
```

And then do a loop to insert them into the database like this:

```
foreach($xml as $element)
{
    $PDO->prepare('INSERT .....');
    $PDO->bindParam(blah,blah);
    $PDO->execute()
}
```

Comment: Tha problem is that var_dump($xml) returns object(SimpleXMLElement)#1685 (0) { }, while var_dump($line) returns a list of numeric values (as it was expected). so, how can I know the names of parameters?

Comment: Is the data in $line valid XML? I'm not sure why it should give you an error. You can do the names of the parameters like this $line['param1'] and so on

Comment: var_dump doesn't work well with SimpleXML objects. Your XML node is probably fine just var_dump doesn't see it

Comment: @GusGus surrond your var dump with <pre>. 
`echo '<pre>'; var_dump(xml); echo '</pre>';`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to pull all file to a table,
You can import it using SQL statements.

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'your_xml_file.xml' 
INTO TABLE your_table_name(field_one,field_two,....);
```

[See Load XML](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html)